# Why is the texture of my chocolate chip cookies foamy?

Tags: baking, cookies, texture

The last couple of batches of my chocolate chip cookies went from delicous to foamy tasting although I was using the same recipe and ingredients and sam measuring methods. I'm confused as to why the texture changed so drastically.

Comment: Do you mean 'cakey'?

Comment: "foamy tasting" - do you mean their structure was too light, like a foam, or do you mean their taste reminded you of soap?

Answer (score 3):

Your dough warmed up and the fat started to melt.  In between batches, keep the dough cold in the fridge.

Over-mixing the dough will also contribute to cake like cookies if a whole batch comes out like that.